# Which type of wing would be a better option for fixed-wing UAV? Mid or low?

Tags: general-aviation, unmanned-aerial-vehicle, fixed-wing

In the context of VTOL hybrid Fixed-wing tiltrotor UAV, for the operation that would require low weight and more maneuverability for agricultural crop surveying, which option would be a good choice, mid-wing or low-wing? The high-wing can be eliminated due to its less maneuverability and doesn't offer any significant advantages(Is what I think) or enlighten me if high-wing can be a good option for the above purpose.

Comment: A tilt rotor will blow the crops down.  A lot of folks still use biplanes (or a high wing aircraft for better ground visibility).  Avoid going [Belphegor](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/PZL_M-15_Belphegor) as well.

Comment: I suppose that the tilt rotors will be placed on the wingtips, just like the [V-22](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_Boeing_V-22_Osprey); if so, high wing is the way forward.